# javascript regular expressions as functions?

Tags: javascript, regex

Apparently, back in Firefox 3.6, the following was legitimate:

```
/[0-9]{3}/('23 2 34 678 9 09')
```

and the result was '678'.

FF8 isn't having any. What's the right syntax now?

Comment: This really depends on what you want to do... there's `test` and `exec`, and strings have `match`, `split` (and `search`?). I suggest: [RegExp documentation, on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Believe it or not, the internal unit tests of HtmlUnit have this code, and the desired result is the matched string if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want

```
/[0-9]{3}/.test('23 2 34 678 9 09');
```

or

```
/[0-9]{3}/.exec('23 2 34 678 9 09');
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would need that syntax but here's something for the lulz:

```
RegExp = (function(){
    var old = RegExp;
    return function(){
        return old.prototype.exec.bind( old.apply( this, arguments ) );
    };
})()
```

Then:

```
new RegExp( "[0-9]{3}" )('23 2 34 678 9 09')
//["678"]
```

Note that the hacked constructor won't be invoked when using literals so it only works when using `new RegExp` ;P

Answer (score 2):

See this discussion : http://whereswalden.com/2011/03/06/javascript-change-in-firefox-5-not-4-and-in-other-browsers-regular-expressions-cant-be-called-like-functions/